# JHipster entity generator not generating entity properly. missing "jhi" word

Tags: jhipster

Hi there i'm using jhipster 4.9.0 and while i'm generating entity with jhipster sub entity generator it creates all the files but it does not add jhi key word in the files.

Like 
    <-alert>
    @Component({
        selector: '-abcd-zyx',
        templateUrl: './abcd-zyx.component.html'
    })

Answer (score 0):

The jhi prefix is only used in the database(liquibase) to avoid using key words.

Comment: Thank you @Ckram for replying. actually i'm talking about the front end generation. its not generating the front-end as it did in the past. 4.8.0 release. e.g. alter tag is missing jhi keyword. <jhi-alert></jhi-alter>